# in app purchase android with adobe air

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-checkout, air-android

I need to write an app for Android with Adobe AIR with payments capabilities. So I want to give user ability to buy some products in application. In iOS - there is In App Purchase, in Android - Google checkout. So the question is: can I use google checkout in Adobe AIR? I didn't find any API for this. Am I wrong? Is there any API for this? If no - what can I use for that? Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using the Native Extension feature of Adobe AIR.  You can read more about how that works here:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/developing-native-extensions-air.html

Also, there is a extension prebuilt that handles all this for you.  Full disclosure, it is a commercial extension and I am the author:

http://www.milkmangames.com/blog/2011/12/28/announcing-android-in-app-purchases-for-adobe-air/

Answer (score 0):

Google checkout isn't accessible from Air applications, there are only SDKs for
Java, .NET, PHP and other languages accept Action Script 3.

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samplecode.html